# show xml data in one column in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i am new to jqgrid and have requirement where i load xml data and display on browser. i have object like below

```
          Object
           id
           xmldata
           attribute1
           attribute2
           attribute3
           attribute4
```

i have json in my webpage as

```
        jq("#grid").jqGrid({
        url:'/url',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['Id', 'xml data', 'attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},hidden:true},
            {name:'XMLData',index:'xmldata', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
            {name:'attribute1',index:'attribute1', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
            {name:'attribute2',index:'attribute2', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
            {name:'attribute3',index:'attribute3', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
            {name:'attribute4',index:'attribute4', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},

        ],
```

but the xmldata property is not loading, other data getting loaded on the page. i know the request body is type json and not xml. but i have mixer json and xml data. how to get xml data displayed using json type. or do we have any alertative. i need to display the xml attributes one single column place one below other.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches that can be used. But they deal with data preprocessing.

**1.**
The [XML class](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/XML.html) in the org.json namespace provides you with this functionality.

You have to call the static [toJSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/XML.html#toJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) method :

> Converts a well-formed (but not necessarily valid) XML string into a JSONObject. Some information may be lost in this transformation because JSON is a data format and XML is a document format. XML uses elements, attributes, and content text, while JSON uses unordered collections of name/value pairs and arrays of values. JSON does not does not like to distinguish between elements and attributes. Sequences of similar elements are represented as JSONArrays. Content text may be placed in a "content" member. Comments, prologs, DTDs, and  are ignored.

This will convert the xml to JSON. Next this data can be appended to the object and used as required.

**2.** The other way you can do is in jQuery using function `xml2json(xml,tab)`. For more explanation you can move to this [link](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/). This can be used in your `customformatter` for the column.